# How do I create a wrapper around a component inso that I can pass some props along with all the props of the base component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I want to create a wrapper around a component called [ContentEditable](https://github.com/lovasoa/react-contenteditable), so that I can add a few more props and call the final component `RichTextArea`.

However, when I am creating the component, I am unable to pass the default props of ContentEditable via RichTextArea. This is what I expect:

```
<RichTextArea placeholder="Some placeholder" className="styles" html="<span>Hello</span>">
```

Where `className` and `html` belongs to ContentEditable and `placeholder` belongs to my wrapper.

I get the following error from Typescript:

> No overload matches this call.   Overload 1 of 2, '(props: Readonly):...

What's the correct way to achieve this?
Here's my crude implementation of RichTextArea:

```
import React from 'react';
import ContentEditable from "react-contenteditable";

export interface RichTextAreaProps extends ContentEditable {
    placeholder ?: string
}
const RichTextArea = (props :  RichTextAreaProps) => {
    return (
        <ContentEditable
            {...props }
            html={props.placeholder}
            onChange={e => console.log()}
        />
    );
};

export default (RichTextArea);
```

Could someone point out what I am doing wrong and how should I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You should extend base component props type,

```
import React from 'react';
import ContentEditable from "react-contenteditable";
    // You have to find the type of props passing in the ContentEditable
    export interface RichTextAreaProps extends IContentEditableProps {
        placeholder ?: string
    }
    const RichTextArea = (props :  RichTextAreaProps) => {
        return (
            <ContentEditable
                {...props }
                html={props.placeholder}
                onChange={e => console.log()}
            />
        );
    };
```

You can choose a better way,

```
 export interface RichTextAreaProps {
        placeholder ?: string
        baseComponentProps?: IContentEditableProps;
    }
```

I go through the [library](https://github.com/lovasoa/react-contenteditable/blob/master/src/react-contenteditable.tsx) you used, and I found the props type at bottom of this link.

```
export interface Props extends DivProps {
  html: string,
  disabled?: boolean,
  tagName?: string,
  className?: string,
  style?: Object,
  innerRef?: React.RefObject<HTMLElement> | Function,
}
```

You can use it like,

```
export interface RichTextAreaProps extends Props{
            placeholder ?: string
        }
```

Hope this can help!

Comment: It gives the following error: TS2769: ```No overload matches this call.   Overload 1 of 2, '(props: Readonly<Props>): ContentEditable', gave the following error.     Type '{ html: string; onChange: (e: ContentEditableEvent) => void; placeholder?: string; disabled?: boolean; tagName?: string; className?: string; style?: Object; innerRef?: Function | RefObject<...>; ... 251 more ...; onTransitionEndCapture?: (event: TransitionEvent<...>) => void; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicClassAttributes<ContentEditable>'.       Types of property 'ref' are incompatible...```

Comment: ` <RichTextArea placeholder="hello" className="classes"/>`